# Possible value of function

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$. Here, $a,b,c$ are integers. If $f(1)=f(6)=0$ then find a possible value of $f(4)$.

I do not know how to solve these type of problems. So can anyone please provide me a short but explaining solution for this problem as an example, so that I can apply this technique for other similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

$f = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the roots. You are told that $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 6$. You need to express $a, b, c$ in terms of the one unknown root and then find $f(4)$.

Comment: Hellow sir, did not clearly get your method. can you give one more line to your solution?. I

Comment: I overcomplicated. $f(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$. If we substitute the known values $x = 4, x_1 = 1, x_2 = 6$ then $f(4) = (4-1)(4-6)(4-x_3) = 6x_3+24$

Comment: This doesn't take into account the additional constraint that the coefficients are integers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, it doesn't violate the constraint either, does it? Considering that $a = -1 -6-x_3$, requiring integer $x_3$ is the same as requiring integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then for any integers $a$ and $b$, we have

$$ a -b | f(a) - f(b).$$

Hence, show that $ 6 \mid f(4)$ (requires 1 step).

It is easy to verify that this is necessary condition, is also sufficient.